# Detect message's name of sent image

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm using a pokecord bot on my discord server, and I also have my own bot in the server. I want to make a feature, that when pokecord sends messageEmbed with pokemon spawn, my bot reacts to it. I tried the `message.content.startsWith()` method, but because it is messageEmbed, it isn't working. Is there some other way to do that? I was thinking, when you click on the pokemon picture, it opens in a new tab, called PokecordSpawn.jpg, maybe it could be done somehow in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the image file name in the `MessageEmbed` like so:

```js
if (message.embeds) {
  if (message.embeds[0].image.url.includes('PokecordSpawn.jpg')) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

You can also use `message.embeds.forEach()` in case the message has multiple embeds

Comment: It throws this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined`

Comment: Still the same error, maybe there could be problem because the embed is sent by my bot on command, although I've put it before the `if(message.author === client.user || !message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || !message.guild) return` because the pokecord sends the spawn embed only once in a while.

Comment: So I have fixed it by changing the first if statement to `message.embeds[0]`, thanks for help!

Comment: And btw the Pokecord bot has been shut down yesterday :D